# How to set length for storing list of string in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using this code in entity for store List

```
@OrderColumn
@ElementCollection(targetClass = java.lang.String.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "view_xmlFile_to_stringList")
private List<String> languageOption = new ArrayList<>();
```

I am saving very long string in list, how can I set length of my list like for simple String variable?

```
@Length(max = 99000)
private String data;
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For defining a list with max size of 20 :

```
@Size(max=20)
private List<String> languageOption = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store large string you must define it inside mapping file. Read the article: 
 http://www.rojotek.com/blog/2007/11/15/storing-large-strings-with-hibernate-3/